# Get all Notifications in onResume

Tags: android, android-activity, notifications, push-notification

I don't have any experience with notifications and after a long time now, I'm feeling really stupid, that I can't make it:

I'm getting push notifications from my server. On click of one, I'm getting the inormations with

```
getIntent().getBundleExtra("extra");
```

in the onResume method.

But if I'm getting a lot of notifications and don't open my application between this, then I'm just getting the last, if I click on the notification. Where are the notifications before? The best would be, if I'm getting a list of bundles or something like this. How can I do that?

Thanks for help, I'm really depressed :)

EDIT:

For better understanding: After receive a GCM I'm make a notification like this:

```
NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        Notification notification = new Notification(icon, title, System.currentTimeMillis());
        notification.sound = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);

        Intent launchIntent = context.getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage(context.getPackageName());
        if (extras != null && launchIntent != null) {
            launchIntent.putExtra("extra", extras);
        }

        PendingIntent intent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, -1, launchIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, title, msg, intent);
        notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
        mNotificationManager.notify(0, notification);
```

Example: I get a GCM and set a notification. If I don't open my application, but get the next GCM, then my first notification will replaced by the new one. This could be many times. After a few notifications i click on it. If the app starts I will get all the notifications, which has been sent. At the moment I just get the last one. How can I get all?

Comment: Sorry i did not read your question properly. Now that I have, by push notification do you mean that your are GCM (Google Cloud Messenger) to receive notifications?

Comment: correct :) need some extra code?

Comment: Yes, I think I can help here.

Comment: Saved an edit :) thanks :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
mNotificationManager.notify(0/* 0 is your notification id */, notification);
```

creates a notification with id 0. Now when you receive another notification and you notify it with the same notificaionId (i.e  0). Hence the latter pending Intent replaces the previous pendingIntent.
Check the explanation for notify() in the docs =>
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/NotificationManager.html

The best option would be to save your data locally in some DB, preferences or the traditional way 
File and whenever you receive a push notification from GCM save it locally and then notify.

Comment: Is it possible to get all my notifications, if i'm setting everytime a unique id?

Comment: @user3621165 If you set different id, then in the notification different notifications will be created . Like If you get 100 notification from GCM server, then you will end up creating 100 different notifications in notification bar, which won't be a good experience as a user. So as I said its better to store your data locally. Try reading about preferences in android which may help you save your data locally or make us of some DB.